# Split value in columns by a delimiter and then Select Distinct

Tags: mysql

**Table structure**:

```
1_column 2_column
-----------------------------
1        data 1; data 2
2        data 3
3        data 1; data 15; data 6
4        data 2; data 3; data 16
5        data 3
```

**Query**: `SELECT DISTINCT 2_column FROM table ORDER BY 1_column`

The output returned is: 4 rows.

```
data 1; data 2
data 3
data 1; data 15, data 6
data 2; data 3; data 16
```

Now I would like to explode the values of the column `2_column` such as data 1, data 2, data 3 etc. and then `SELECT DISTINCT` among the exploded values. How to make this with performance in mind and with MySQL alone?

**Edit: Expected result:**

```
data 1
data 2
data 3
data 6
data 15
data 16
```

Exploded DISTINCT values. 6 rows.

Comment: If you have performance in mind, just have one data per row... This will increase the number of rows and will allow you to use normal MySQL functions to do your bidding. If a change of table structure can be allowed, I would greatly recommend it. Also please add the result you would be expecting for your SELECT DISTINCT, as it will make your words have way more sense.

Comment: @Salketer: Thank you, have noted your suggestions and edited the question too.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, you need to normalise your data. But I guess you can use something like this as a step towards achieving that...

```
SELECT * FROM my_table;
+---------+-------------------------+
| column1 | column2                 |
+---------+-------------------------+
|       1 | data 1; data 2          |
|       2 | data 3                  |
|       3 | data 1; data 15; data 6 |
|       4 | data 2; data 3; data 16 |
|       5 | data 3                  |
+---------+-------------------------+

SELECT * FROM ints;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
+---+

SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column2,';',i),';',-1)) x 
           FROM my_table
              , ints i 
         HAVING x <> '';
+---------+
| x       |
+---------+
| data 1  |
| data 3  |
| data 2  |
| data 15 |
| data 6  |
| data 16 |
+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

The trivial way is the following:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS getresults$$ 
CREATE PROCEDURE getresults()
  BEGIN
    DECLARE ite INT;
    SET @s="";
    select MAX(LENGTH(2_column)-LENGTH(REPLACE(2_column, ";", "")))+1 max 
      FROM mytable INTO ite;

    WHILE (ite>0) DO
       SET @s=concat(@s, 
           "UNION SELECT ltrim(substring_index(
               SUBSTRING_INDEX(2_column, ';', ",ite,"), ';', -1)) data
            FROM mytable ");
    SET ite:=ite-1;
    END WHILE;
    SET @s=mid(@s, 6);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

  END $$
DELIMITER ;
call getresults();

+---------+
| data    |
+---------+
| data 2  |
| data 3  |
| data 6  |
| data 16 |
| data 15 |
| data 1  |
+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I do like Strawberry answer which is more simple than my previous stored procedure

If you assume that you wont have more "pseudo columns" than rows, you can use the next instructions, to bypass the limitation of creating an int table :

```
   SET @a:=0;
   SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(2_column,';',a.nb),';',-1)) data
    FROM mytable,
       (SELECT @a:=@a+1 nb
             FROM mytable
             WHERE @a<
              (SELECT MAX(LENGTH(m1.2_column)
                   -LENGTH(REPLACE(m1.2_column, ";", "")))+1 max
                 FROM mytable m1)) a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use temporary number table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.2_column, ';', n.number), ';', -1)) AS data
FROM 
    (SELECT a.i number
     FROM (SELECT 1 i UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) a
     ORDER BY number) n
JOIN table t
  ON CHAR_LENGTH(t.2_column) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(t.2_column, ';', '')) >= n.number - 1
ORDER BY data;
```